# MS Access does not recognize "classic" VBA functions

Tags: forms, vba, subprocess, libraries

I am using the following function to vertically align labels in a form.

```
Private Sub VerticallyCenter(ctl As control)
    Dim lngHeight As Long
    lngHeight = fTextHeight(ctl)
    ' Rounding will result in a 1 to 2 pixel margin of error
    ' of every control before it renders text.
    ctl.TopMargin = ((ctl.Height - lngHeight) / 2)
End Sub
```

However, when I compile it, it says that fTextHeight() is not defined. I have the same error on other "classic" VBA Access functions as DirectCast() or CType(). It looks like my Access is not loading VBA Libraries.

Comment: Are you sure that DirectCast and CType are valid VBA and not VB (or vb.net)?

Comment: This seems to be from some code that is swimming through various code forums. I have never heard of **fTextHeight** before. I assume it is come custom function, not a built-in function. Did you get this code from some forum?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

Like I said, fTextHeight is a custom function. It is contained in the module `modTextHeightWidth` in the zipped .mdb downloadable from here: http://www.lebans.com/textwidth-height.htm